# Ruby character encoding problems in netbeans and command wíndow

Tags: ruby, unicode, netbeans, encoding

I use netbeans as development IDE and runs the application from cmd but have problems to display ISO 8859-1 characters like åäö correct in both cmd window and when I run the application from netbeans

**Question:** What is best practice to set it up

Right now I do

```
@output.puts indent + "V" + 132.chr + "lkommen till Ruby Camping!"
```

to get **ä**

**My environment**

**>chcp 65001**

```
Active code page: 65001
```

**>ruby main.rb**

```
Source encoding: <Encoding:US-ASCII>
Default external: #<Encoding:UTF-8>
Default internal: nil
Locale charmap: "CP65001"
```

where I have in the code

```
def self.printEncoding
    puts "Source encoding: #{__ENCODING__.inspect}" if defined? __ENCODING__
    if defined? Environment::Encoding
      puts "Default external: #{Encoding.default_external.inspect}"
      puts "Default internal: #{Encoding.default_internal.inspect}"
      puts "Locale charmap: #{ Encoding.locale_charmap.inspect}"
    end
    puts "LANG environment variable: #{ENV['LANG'].inspect}" unless ENV['LANG'].nil?
  end
```

**>ruby -v**
ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [i386-mingw32]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use non-ASCII characters in your source file, you need to declare the encoding of the source file. The very first line of the source file (or the second, if you have a shebang line) needs to be a comment line which (roughly) matches the regexp

```
#.*?coding[:=]?\s+(.*)(?:\s+.*)?
```

In other words: a comment line which starts with some stuff, then contains the string `coding` followed by an optional symbol followed by a valid encoding name followed by some other stuff.

So, if you put

```
# coding: ISO-8859-1
```

at the top of your file, you should be okay. Note that the regexp is explicitly designed to be compatible with editors such as Vim:

```
# vim: fileencoding=UTF-8 ft=ruby syn=ruby ts=2 sw=2 ai eol et si
```

Or Emacs:

```
# *-* mode: ruby; coding: utf-8; tab-width: 2; indent-tabs-mode: nil *-*
```

One thing that always trips me up, is that Ruby *does not* always automatically transcode strings. You have to transcode them yourself:

```
puts 'ä'
# => ├ñ

puts 'ä'.encode($>.external_encoding || Encoding.default_external)
# => ä
```

Comment: Thanks but no success found a could link on the subject and maybe it is netbeans or the cmd window that is the problem

http://blog.grayproductions.net/categories/character_encodings

My result right now http://content.screencast.com/users/salgo60/folders/Snagit/media/4e320726-1ecf-4f68-9ea9-21db0d82ee00/06.06.2010-12.51.15.png

Comment: @salgo60: Did you see my edit? I thought that Ruby did the transcoding automatically, but apparently that is not the case. You have to transcode the string yourself, before printing it. (Actually, according to my own intuition as well as James Edward Gray II's articles, you should *not* have to do that: strings should get converted to the IO object's (`$>` in this case) external encoding automatically. Something is not quite right about my understanding of Ruby 1.9 m17n.)

Comment: Thanks
it works in the command window where I run Ruby 1.9
but still netbeans seems give me some "unexpected characters"

Source encoding: #<Encoding:ISO-8859-1>
Default external: #<Encoding:UTF-8>
Default internal: nil
Locale charmap: "CP850"
        VÃ¤lkommen till Ruby Camping!

I am satiesfied with this....